# How to open URL in new Browser from Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight-5.0

We have MVVM Silverlight application. I am trying to open web url from button click event which happen on client side viewmodel and through invoke method needs to open web url in new browser.

I am using Process.Start method as describe below in Server side code.

```
   var URL = @"http://SiteSelect.aspx";
   SecureString secure = new SecureString();
   char[] passwordChars = Properties.Settings.Default.Password.ToCharArray();
   //converting string to securestring...found from internet
    foreach (char c in passwordChars)
           {
             secure.AppendChar(c);
           }
    Process.Start(URL,"",Properties.Settings.Default.User,secure,"agent");
```

this throws an error related to user name and password. I checked user name and password is correct. Anyone have solution or any other method I can able to use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You create a helper class:

```
public static class CommonHelper
{
    private class HyperlinkButtonWrapper : HyperlinkButton
    {
        public void OpenURL(string navigateUri)
        {
            OpenURL(new Uri(navigateUri, UriKind.Absolute));
        }

        public void OpenURL(Uri navigateUri)
        {
            base.NavigateUri = navigateUri;
            base.TargetName = "_blank";
            base.OnClick();
        }
    }

    public static void OpenURL(string navigateUri)
    {
        new HyperlinkButtonWrapper().OpenURL(navigateUri);
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
CommonHelper.OpenURL(@"http://SiteSelect.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks but I also have to pass credential... how I can able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as well :

```
using System.Windows.Browser;
var uri = new Uri("http://foo.fr");
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank");
```

Easiest way to pass credentials is to put them in the URL, however it's not very secured. Ie:

http://user:password@foo.fr

Comment: Nice and short solution, but does not work for "out of browser" applications.